# Setting the domain of a function in Python SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to set the domain of a math. function. For example, when I define the following expression

```
>>> import sympy as syp
>>> x = syp.Symbol('x')
>>> miles_to_km = x * 1.609344
>>> miles_to_km.evalf()
1.609344*x
```

Is it possible to limit the domain so that x is in the range [0, inf)? So the goal is that I could then use the `sympy.plot` function that produces a graph that starts at 0 and only includes positive x-values in contrast to

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check the manual by doing:

```
help(syp.plot)
```

You will get:

> ...
>
> `expr` : Expression representing the function of single variable
>
> `range`: (x, 0, 5), A 3-tuple denoting the range of the free variable.
>
> ...

So, you can:

```
>>> import sympy as syp
>>> x = syp.Symbol('x')
>>> miles_to_km = x * 1.609344
>>> syp.plot(miles_to_km, (x,0,10))
```

which will give you the following output:

[image]